# [Vue warn]: Error in created hook: "TypeError: store.hasModule is not a function"

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have vue component which creates own store in `created()` hook like this:

```
    created: function(){
        const store = this.$store;
        
        var moduleArr = ['block', 'Comment'];
        
        if(!store.hasModule(moduleArr)){
            store.registerModule(moduleArr, CommentStore);
        }
    },
```

But I've got the error:

> [Vue warn]: Error in created hook: "TypeError: store.hasModule is not
> a function"

According to the doc from here https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html :

> Note that you may check if the module is already registered to the
> store or not via store.hasModule(moduleName) method.

What did gone wrong?

Comment: What is `hasModule  && registerModule `?, are they actions or getters or mutations?

Comment: Can you add here your store configuration.

Comment: @Naren, `hasModule  && registerModule` - these are methods of vuex https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#dynamic-module-registration .

Comment: @Naren, I've updated my vue from 2.6.10 to 2.6.12 and error has gone. Thank you for attention.

Comment: Oh Cool, Good to know!, Those are predefined modules. Gotcha